# Django how to improve security of password reset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I setup an password reset option for my users. But I found few security risk:

**1) password reset link not expiring:** Right now my password reset link not expiring. I  want password reset link can be use only one time. User can't use it second time for change his password

**2) How to prevent password change if user change the value of HTML** : Let you explain. I have an html hidden input filed like this `<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{user_id}}">` if user change the html value of `user_id` then I want to prevent password changing. here is my code:

**token.py** for sent password reset link to mail

```
def send_forget_password_mail(email,token):
    subject = 'EXAMPLE.COM Password Reset Link'
    message = f'hi your forgot password link http://127.0.0.1:8000/change-password/{token}'
    email_from = 'noreply@EXAMPLE.com'
    recipient_list =[email]
    send_mail(subject,message,email_from,recipient_list)
    return True
```

views.py

This is the forget password view where user submit mail for get password reset link. Here I also saving token in user profile.

```
def ForgetPassword(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       email = request.POST["email"]
       User = get_user_model()
       if not User.objects.filter(email=email).first():
           messages.success(request, "Invalid mail")
           return redirect('members:rest-password') 
       user_obj = User.objects.get(email=email)
       print(user_obj)
       token = str(uuid.uuid4())
       profile_obj = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user_obj)
       profile_obj.forget_password_token = token
       profile_obj.save()
       send_forget_password_mail(user_obj.email,token) 
       messages.success(request, "An password reset link sent to your email")
       return redirect('members:reset-password')     
    return render(request, 'members/password_reset_form.html')
```

This is the view where user changing his password.

```
def ChangePassword(request,token):
    profile_obj = UserProfile.objects.filter(forget_password_token=token).first()
    User = get_user_model()
    print(profile_obj)
    if request.method == "POST":
       password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
       password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
       user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
       if user_id is None:
           messages.success(request, "user not found")
           return redirect(f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/change-password/{token}')
       if password1 != password2:
            messages.success(request, "password didn't match")
            return redirect(f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/change-password/{token}')
       
       user_obj = User.objects.get(id =user_id)
       user_obj.set_password(password1)
       user_obj.save()
       messages.success(request, "your password sucessfully changed")
       return redirect('members:login')


    context ={'user_id':profile_obj.user.id}
    print(context)
    return render(request,'members/password_change.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you can use Django's settings parameter `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS` to reduce the amount of days for the link timeout. You can read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout-days). I am not entirely sure it is possible to make it a one time use link.

Regarding the second question, you can encrypt it in some way that you want.

For example, you can add a template filter that will encrypt your id in which ever way you want. You can have it run caesar encryption or xor encryption with extra text padding to make it more difficult to decrypt.
Something along the lines of `<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{user_id|caesar}}">`

This way it is less likely that changing the user id will matter, because you can return an error on submission if the user id doesn't exist, after decryption.